Visual Studio References in Editor
How do I get rid of the references in the Visual Studio text editor?

Does this answer your question? How to hide reference counts in VS2013?

Your issue might be due to the CodeLens feature being enabled. To disable CodeLens, which provides real-time information and actions related to your code directly within the Visual Studio code editor, follow these steps:
Open Visual Studio.

Click on the "Tools" menu at the top.
Select "Options" from the drop-down menu.
In the "Options" window, type "CodeLens" into the search bar.
Uncheck the box next to "Enable CodeLens."

By following these steps, you can disable the CodeLens feature in Visual Studio. I hope this helps. Have a great day!
